# Django: How i can dislay the resulat of some calculation after press a button on the same page

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

i want to display the result of some calculation after click on a button,
the thing that I have go and call the fields-calculated after calculation  in the same template html.

but the result is gone to another page because i have specified on the `urls.py` another route url.

**Here is the code of the 2 functions: one is for calculation and the other one is for the home page (where is contain the fields-data that i have entered and  the button of calculation), and i want to display there the result of calculation that i have did on the first function in the views.py:**

```
@login_required 
def calcul_resultat(request): 
    resultat = float(0)
    ch_permanent = request.POST.get('ch_permanent', False)
    ch_exp = request.POST.get('ch_exp', False)
    calcul=""
    calcul_exp=""
    calcul_md=""
    if not (ch_permanent and ch_exp):
        return HttpResponse({"result" :resultat})
    else:
        float_ch_exp = float(ch_exp)
        resultat = 2.4 * float_ch_exp
        calcul += "<strong>Calculation of Dweight: </strong>"
        calcul += str(resultat)
        float_ch_permanent = float(ch_permanent)
        resultat = 3.6 * float_ch_permanent
        calcul_exp += "<strong>Calculation of the load: </strong>"
        calcul_exp += str(resultat) 
        float_calcul_exp = float(2.4 * float_ch_exp)
        float_calcul_per = float(3.6 * float_ch_permanent)
        float_length = float(length)
        resultat += (float_calcul_exp * float_length)
        calcul_md += "<strong>Calculation moment </strong>"
        calcul_md += str(resultat)     
        return render(request,'pages/home.html',{'calcul':calcul, 'calcul_exp':calcul_exp, 'calcul_md':calcul_md})
```

and Here it is the function of home in the `views.py`

@login_required

```
def home(request):
    form = FormsCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormsCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', {'form': form})
```

Here How i have call them in the same `template home.html` after the button:

```
<div id ="loading">
  <form action="{% url 'calcul_resultat' %}" method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="btn_calculer">Calculate</button>
      <br/>
    {{ calcul | safe }}
      <br/>
    {{ calcul_exp | safe }}
    <br>
    {{ calcul_md | safe }}       
</form>  </div>
```

and here is the `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('home/calcul/', views.calcul_resultat, name='calcul_resultat')
]
```

So Please How i can reach the goal of displaying the calculation-result that I have called them on the same html template:

```
    {{ calcul | safe }}
    {{ calcul_exp | safe }}
    {{ calcul_md | safe }}
```

to be on the same page when i click on the button.

Help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can not update a HTML page without reloading it with pure HTML. For that you need at least some JavaScript. Most people will use AJAX or you can look into a new framework called HTMX.

Comment: Here you can learn more about AJAX with JQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: I have see the example from the link you have sent to me , I have write            <script>
$("#loading").load("home.html");
</script>                                                                                                                 ("loading" is the "id" of the "div" of the Form that i want to reload with the result in the template) 
on the end of the html template where i have called the fields-calculated But it does not work. 
should ido another thing before using this jquery ajax or install something!

Comment: yes. you need to load the jquery library on your HTML page for any jquery command to work: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: you also need to put all jquery commands into the ready() function, so they are only called once the HTML page is fully rendered, explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp